# Creating a scalable repeating background for a column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background-image

I'm having some issues with bootstrap and creating a scalable column background.

In a single row, I have a column with a fluid image (the top of the box), a column below, this column has a CSS class to give it a repeating background across the Y axis, and finally a column below with another fluid image (the bottom of the box).

So the idea being these two images are the top and bottom of the box, then the centre background image will repeat along the Y and line up perfectly with the two images, making it look like a closed box, no matter the length of the content.

However, no matter what I try the centre box background image is always misaligned so it bleeds out a little (see image below). Can someone give me a little help to get this lined up?

[image]

I'm using the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 order-2">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/games/crabs/framework/box-top.png" alt="What is Crabs">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 order-3 crabs-textbox-centre">
        <h1 class="text-center">
            <span class="text-danger strong">
                CRABS is an arena based, multiplayer, party brawler extravaganza!
            </span>
            <br>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="text-center">
            Battle friends or AI across a range of unique and exciting game modes in competitive and co-op local couch play.
        </h2>
        <h2 class="text-center">
            Current and next-gen platforms.
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 order-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/games/crabs/framework/box-bottom.png" alt="What is Crabs">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.crabs-textbox-centre
    padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
    background-image: url("../img/games/crabs/framework/box-centre.png");
    height: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
```

Comment: Can you share the images seperately

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for commenting fatalcoder... i've fixed the issue using the following setup:

I created two new CSS style items each with their own background for the top and bottom sections, i then simply add these columns above.

Any mobile specific sizing is done via a media query, see code below:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 order-1 crabs-textbox-top">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 order-2 crabs-textbox-centre">
            <h1 class="text-center"><span class="text-danger strong">CRABS is an arena based, multiplayer, party brawler extravaganza!</span><br></h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">Battle friends or AI across a range of unique and exciting game modes in competitive and co-op local couch play.</h2>
            <h2 class="text-center">Current and next-gen platforms.</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 order-3 crabs-textbox-bottom">
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.crabs-textbox-top{
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    height: 64px;
    background-image: url("../img/games/crabs/framework/box-top.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 95%;
    background-position: bottom center;
}

.crabs-textbox-centre{
    padding: 0 60px 0 60px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url("../img/games/crabs/framework/box-centre.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 95%;
    background-position: center center;
}

.crabs-textbox-bottom{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    height: 64px;
    background-image: url("../img/games/crabs/framework/box-bottom.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 95%;
    background-position: top center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.crabs-textbox-top{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    height: 30px;
    }

.crabs-textbox-bottom{
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    height: 30px;
    }
    
}
```